# Multiply a css class div element in Jquery or Javascript without the HTML

Tags: jquery, html

My problem is simple,

I have a div class element looking like this:

```
<div class="square">

<div class ="inner">
<img src="square.jpg" alt="square"> 
</div>
```

Now, what I want to do is duplicate/multiply the ".square" element until it fills the space of a parent div "#wrapper". But I don't want to copy paste the element 200 times in HTML, so I was wondering if there is a javascript / jquery option for this.

Another question would be if I can somehow make the multiplication stop when the element filled the whole parent div space.

I am more of a newbie in the programming area, but always eager to learn and discover, so If for some my question seems silly or has an obvious answer please share it so I might remember it as being silly too one day.

Comment: Why don't you just use a background image?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - He probably needs them (cells) to be responsive to events etc.

Comment: Techfoobar is right. I need them to be cells, and I need them to be responsive too.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is basic math. You determine the total available area and keep adding elements as long as the total used area is lesser than the total available area.

```
var outer = $('.square'), inner = $('.inner')
    totalArea = outer.width() * outer.height(),

    usedArea = inner.outerWidth() * inner.outerHeight();

while(usedArea < totalArea) {
    $('<div/>').addClass('inner').appendTo(outer);
    usedArea += inner.outerWidth() * inner.outerHeight();
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dRWKQ/1/)**

Comment: This looks great techfoobar, but the totalArea should be the window size which is variable as you know. And the squares should be variable as well. This is what I came up with (except the javascript) so far :http://jsfiddle.net/6Fz84/11/

Comment: So in less words I need the whole thing to be responsive. And I need them cells because I want to make them disappear randomly until only 3 of them are left (in the center) which will act as buttons. I am sorry if I am confusing you, I will try to be as explicit as I can. (Meanwhile I will try to adapt your previous answer)

Comment: Or you can define the area code in a function and call them on window resize as well..

Comment: I tried replacing outer.width() and outer.height() with (window).width() and (widow).height() but the result is a bit chaotic

Comment: Techfoobar if you think you could explain a bit further your idea of a function for the area code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for the time, I will keep experimenting until then.

Comment: You need that red image as the background - or as each tile?

Comment: I need it for each tile. I need each tile to be red, it's not necessary to be that image (background color would do it just as well).

Comment: Couldn't get it to work when the cell sizes are responsive. For fixed sized cells this should work - http://jsfiddle.net/dRWKQ/27/ - Note that it is window size aware as well (try resizing the result pane).

Comment: That looks great techfoobar, but I still get white space on left and bottom when the size of the window doesn't allow another row of column of square to fit in. I just had an idea that maybe could work: What if we have a fixed number of squares to fill the window and make only the space between them vary?